# ReactJS, how to edit a textarea and update the value when displaying the textareas from database?

Tags: mysql, database, reactjs

I am currently using node.js (for database storage using mySQL) and react.js (to display all text areas)

I'm not too sure how to do this, if I have a loop of textareas given from database, how would I be able to edit the value inside textarea and be able to retrieve that value in order to update it in my database when i click on 'Save data' button.

```
const WorkInProgressHLEDevDays = () =>{
return (
<tr>
<th> TEXTAREAs </th>
{this.state.WIPHLEsData.map((HLEDevDayTextAreas, i) => (
    <td key={i}>
    <textarea className="HLEDevDays"  onChange={this.handleChange} value={HLEDevDayTextAreas.HLEDevDays} spellcheck="false">

    </textarea>
    </td>

))}


</tr>
```

)
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to implement this. The easiest is to make your components uncontrolled, though it's the least recommended one according to facebook:

```
{this.state.WIPHLEsData.map((HLEDevDayTextAreas, i) => (
  <td key={i}>
    <textarea
      name={`HLEDevDays_${i}`}
      className="HLEDevDays"
      defaultValue={HLEDevDayTextAreas.HLEDevDays}
      spellcheck="false"
    />
  </td>
)}
```

As the name suggests, React doesn't manage the state of each textarea, but lets your browser do that via regular DOM mutations. If you wrap this whole thing in a `form`, you will be able to read the values on your back-end (via the `name` attribute).

Comment: **name={`HLEDevDays_${i}`}** what does this do exactly? And perfect, im able to do edit the textareas with **defaultValue={HLEDevDayTextAreas.HLEDevDays}** :),  now the thing is, how would I grab the values for each textarea, I  was thinking of setting a state array value, say HLEDevDaysUserInputs: [],  set its state to the values that i would be able to get from each textarea value displayed. But my question is how would i get these textarea values for each row?

Comment: It's called *template literals*, look it up :) You said you wanted the values in your back-end, right? If so, just submit your form as post and you should be able to access them there by their name value.

Comment: What im trying to do after displaying the values from database in each textarea is: When user inputs any text within textarea for a specific row, once user clicks on the button 'Save data', when I refresh my page, i'll be able to view what the user inputted and saved.

Comment: I have already obtained the values from back-end, i'm trying to save the data the user inputs by updating the column HLEDevDays in my database based on which textarea the user inputs a value in.

Comment: @bobb1213131, do you have a way, in your back-end to receive this data? Like via a post request or something? This isn't *just* a React question.

Comment: hey chris, it seems that the defaultValue prop doesn't work anymore in my form... Is there any other workaround for it ?

Comment: @bobb1213131, *anymore*? Did it break? No workaround, but you can use controlled components instead and use `value`.

Comment: controlled components meaning with an onChange and a value correct?

Comment: is it possible because I npm installed some versions that can break it ? and thanks!